# what is this return statement doing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, telerik

In the code sample below, the return statement uses some syntax that seems strange to me.  It's returning a new Json result but initializing it with the object that is passed in as a parameter? Can someone please explain the return statement?

```
[AcceptVerbs("Post")]
public ActionResult EditingInline_Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ProductViewModel product)
{            
    if (product != null)
    {                
        productService.Destroy(product);                
    }

    return Json(new[] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Returning Json data, I typically do something like this:

```
// GET: api/authors
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get()
{
    return Json(_authorRepository.List());
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://doylestowncoder.com/2014/04/14/kendoui-understanding-todatasourceresult/

Comment: nobody can explain that better than the documentations of the product that you're working on. however, from the looks of it, the return data is the result of the request applied to some model. The method is trying to destroy something and the return value of that action naturally would contain some result data.

Comment: Why do you think that the first version functions any differently than your version? The `Json` method takes in an object that will be serialized to JSON in the HTTP response. How that object is originally created is inconsequential.

Comment: I think its the object creation, or rather the statement new[] { product } that seems strange.  Its obvious its creating a new array, but the { } is creating an object?

Comment: To answer simple: `new[] { product }` creates a new array which contains 1 element _(product)_ so the `ToDataSourceResult` will handle it as an array _(instead of 1 object)_

Comment: @bitshift no, the `{ }` has nothing to do with json here... it is c# definition; used to define an array and fill it with elements _(in this case only 1 product)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it to first be creating an array which it populates with the product. It then uses the ToDataSourceResult method which converts this to Json.

The "ToDataSourceResult" seems to be a method used with Teleriks Kendo UI Grid in order to display data from JSON:

https://doylestowncoder.com/2014/04/14/kendoui-understanding-todatasourceresult/

Comment: Almost right, It creates an array and fills it with 1 product. Then the array is converted to a  `DataSourceResult` which gets converted to JSON.

Comment: Thank you.  I had forgot how simple arrays are declared and initialized, eg.  int[] array2 = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };